# Shell script to iterate through files with only one '4' in the file name

Tags: shell

I am trying to iterate through files in the same directory with only one 4 in them.

Here is what I have so far. The problem with my current script is that files with any number of 4's get selected, not files with only one 4.

```
for i in *4*.cpp;
do

...
```

Sort of like `[!4]` but for any number of non 4 characters.
*http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/wildcards.html

I want to iterate through file names such as me4.cpp, 4.cpp, and hi4hi.cpp

I want to ignore file names such as lala.cpp, 44.cpp, 4hi4.cpp

Thank you!

Figured it out. I tried [!4]* on a whim.
Oops turned out I didn't. That is interpreted as ([!4]) then (*)

Comment: `[!4]*` doesn't include `4.cpp` and includes `lala.cpp`. Another solution would be to use `find -regex`, but I don't know what kind of an expression to use in this case...

Comment: `[!4]*` includes `a44.cpp`, `a444.cpp`, `a4444.cpp`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The `grep` style regex you need is:

```
^[^4]*4[^4]*$
```

A bunch of not-4's after the start of the line, a 4, and another bunch of not-4's to the end of the line.

In pure shell, consider using a `case` statement:

```
 for file in *4*.cpp
 do
     case "$file" in
     (*4*4*) : Ignore;;
     (*)     : Process;;
     esac
 done
```

That looks for names containing 4's, and then ignores those containing 2 or more 4's.

Comment: This, again, doesn't include `4.cpp`. You could incorporate that grep syntax into the globbing feature of Bash by doing `for i in [^4]*4[^4]*`.

Comment: @Daniel: Why doesn't it include 4.cpp?  The pattern `*4*.cpp` certainly includes `4.cpp`; the pattern `*4*4*` does not exclude it.  Are you thinking of regexes instead of shell globbing.  These stars are globs; in regex terms, each `*` is equivalent to `.*` (zero or more of any character), not a repeat of the previous character.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `find`

```
find ./ -regex "<regular expression>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *([^4])4*([^4]).cpp; ...
```

where `*([^4])` means zero or more characters that are not "4"